# Ruby - Generate array of comma separated arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a Google chart using GoogleVisualr.

This input works:

```
data_table.add_rows([
      ['04/14', 1],  
      ['04/15', 2], 
      ['04/16', 3], 
      ['04/17', 4], 
      ['04/18', 5], 
      ['04/19', 1], 
      ['04/20', 12], 
      ['04/21', 13], 
      ['04/24', 14], 
      ['04/14', 15], 
      ['04/24', 16], 
      ['04/22', 17], 
      ['04/14', 18], 
      ['04/4', 19], 
    ])
```

I am currently using:

```
Product.find(:all, :order => "created_at ASC").each do |p|
    data_table.add_rows([
     [p.created_at.strftime("%m/%d"), p.rating]
    ])
```

which returns:

```
01/13
2
01/20
3
02/22
2
03/14
2
03/19
2
04/14
1
04/15
2
04/17
2
05/14
2
05/14
2
05/14
2
05/14
2...
```

How can I format my array to match what GoogleVisualr requires:

> [ [data, value], [date, value]...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use a loop, just use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
rows = Product.all.order("created_at ASC").map do |p| 
 [p.created_at.strftime("%m/%d"), p.rating]
end
data_table.add_rows(rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code "Product.find(:all, :order => "created_at ASC")" you can create a :scope and your controller assigns @products = Product.order_by_created

```
@products.inject([]) do {|result, p| result << [p.created_at.strftime("%m/%d"), p.rating])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already looping over each row, you can just use `DataTable#add_row`.

```
Product.find(:all, :order => "created_at ASC").each do |p|
  data_table.add_row([p.created_at.strftime("%m/%d"), p.rating])
end
```

Comment: This does not generate new rows. I get the same out put as interpolating the data and rating values. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550285/creating-charts-with-googlevisualr

Answer (score 0):

Make it into a string and interpolate your values within it.

```
puts "data_table.add_rows(["
Product.find(:all, :order => "created_at ASC").each do |p|
  puts "['#{p.created_at.strftime("%m/%d")}', #{p.rating}],"
end
puts "    ])"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
pry(main)> result = []
=> []
pry(main)> Project.find(:all, :order => "created_at ASC").each do |p|
pry(main)*   result << [p.created_at.strftime("%m/%d"), p.id]
pry(main)* end  
pry(main)> result
=> [["02/05", 1],
["02/14", 6],
["02/15", 7],
["02/18", 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way, but premature optimisation is the root of all evil:

```
@products = Product.all(:order => 'created_at ASC')  
@csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
        csv << ["Secret", "Timestamp"]
        @products.each { |secret|
                csv << ["#{secret.story}", "#{secret.updated_at.strftime('%s')}"]
        }
    end
@csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Google Visualr API  (https://github.com/winston/google_visualr) on Winston's Github page, you will see that the `add_rows` method requires a nested array, where each element of the array is another array of size (length) 2. The first element `e[0]` is the date and the second element `e[1]` is the data value for that date. Pass your data in this format, and it should work correctly.

It looks like your code should already be doing that, as far as we can tell from here without actually being on your machine. However, your code is calling the `add_rows` method for each iteration in your `each` method, and supplying the `data_table.add_rows` method with a nested array that only has **one** array inside of it.

So instead of looking like this:

`[ ['04/14', 1],
   ['04/15', 2], 
   ['04/16', 3], 
   ['04/17', 4] ]`

and calling `add_rows` just one time like you would normally do, you are calling `add_rows` over and over again like this:

`add_rows ( [ ['04/14', 1] ] )`

`add_rows ( [ ['04/15', 2] ] )`

`add_rows ( [ ['04/16', 3] ] )`

`add_rows ( [ ['04/17', 4] ] )`

once for each data point.

What you should do is use your `each` iterator to put each date and its corresponding data value into an array, then call `add_rows` with that array as the parameter. Something like this:

```
my_array = []

Product.find(:all, :order => "created_at ASC").each do |p|
  my_array <<  [p.created_at.strftime("%m/%d"), p.rating]
end

data_table.add_rows(my_array)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: **Thilo** has the right idea, if you understand how the `map` iterator works. The `map` method is kind of like the `each` method, except it returns an array consisting of elements that are the result of executing the block for each value. So you are doing the same thing as I suggest, except you're using the `map` method as a syntactic shortcut. Even if you use the `map` method instead of filling in the array yourself with `each`, my comments should help explain what you are doing and why. Good luck!